# How can I use find to select users with a certain amount of disk space usage?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I want to find all users shown in the `/home/` directory whose disk consumption is more than 500MB. The following command works as expected.

```
cd /home/ && du */ -hs
68K     ajay/
902M    john/
250M    websites/
```

From the above example, only `902M john/` should be returned.

How can I make the `find` command output the same results?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will work with "find" command.

Comment: Any particular reason why do you want to use find for this task? I would just do **cd /home/ && du */ -ms | awk '$1 > 500 { print $0 }'**

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer? This seems to working. But how do I get human readable disk consumption figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this only with find, because find acts on individual files, and doesn't have a concept of adding up file sizes. You could pipe the output of find into another tool, but why bother when du does most of the work?

```
du -sm */ | sort -k1,1n | awk '$1 > 500 { sub(/$/, "M", $1); print $0 }'
```

The awk test becomes messy when the "human-readable" suffix in included in the input, because you need to strip off the trailing "M" to do an integer comparison. For the output, personally I'd skip the "M" suffix, but that's what was requested.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you want something like `find`, so here's a scriptlet that does what you ask in `bash` (but doesn't work like find):

```
max_size=$((500*1024))
cd /home/ && du -ks */ | while read size user ; do
  if [ $size -gt $max_size ] ; then
    echo "${user%/} exceeds quota"
  fi
done
```

Example: (with a smaller size):

```
$ du -sk */
2948    a/
4       a b/
640     b/
48      qt/

$ du -ks */ | while read size user ; do if [ $size -gt 600 ] ; then echo "${user%/} exceeds quota" ; fi ; done
a exceeds quota
b exceeds quota
```

The `${user%/}` just removes the trailing slash for extra prettyness.

Comment: The first example worked as expected. In case of second command, the $size is treated as text and not as number.

Comment: @shantanuo: I don't understand that comment. There is only one script above.

Comment: @shantanuo What is your shell? Mat wrote that his answer is for `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the disk usage (in kb) for each user's files in `dir` regardless of where those files are:

```
find dir -printf "%u %b\n" | perl -n -e '@l = split; $sum{$l[0]} += $l[1]; END { foreach(sort(keys(%sum))) { print "$_ ",$sum{$_}/2," KiB\n"; }}'
```

The find command prints the owner and block count of each file and directory in `dir`. The perl command adds the usage into a hash keyed on the username, thus building a sum of each user's file sizes; and then the contents of the hash is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as answer.

I have used **du -ms** to get consistent output that can be processed by awk without additional intervention. You are correct that human readable output is better, so the final output gets processed once again for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

######################################################################
#  AUTHOR: Joe Negron - LOGIC Wizards ~ NYC
#  LICENSE: BuyMe-a-Drinkware: Dual BSD or GPL (pick one)
#  USAGE: byteMe (bytes)
#  ABSTRACT: Converts a numeric parameter to a human readable format.
#  URL: http://www.logicwizards.net/2010/10/19/byteme-a-simple-binary-metrics-bash-script-howto-convert-bytes-into-kb-mb-gb-etc-using-bash-bc/
######################################################################
function byteMe() { # Divides by 2^10 until < 1024 and then append metric suffix
declare -a METRIC=('B' 'KB' 'MB' 'GB' 'TB' 'XB' 'PB') # Array of suffixes
MAGNITUDE=0  # magnitude of 2^10
PRECISION="scale=1" # change this numeric value to inrease decimal precision
UNITS=`echo $1 | tr -d ','`  # numeric arg val (in bytes) to be converted
while [ ${UNITS/.*} -ge 1024 ] # compares integers (b/c no floats in bash)
  do
   UNITS=`echo "$PRECISION; $UNITS/1024" | bc` # floating point math via `bc`
   ((MAGNITUDE++)) # increments counter for array pointer
  done
echo -n "$UNITS${METRIC[$MAGNITUDE]}"
}

cd /home/ && du */ -bs | awk '$1 > 500 { print $0 }' | while read LINE; do
    SIZE=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -f 1)
    HRSIZE=$(byteMe "$SIZE")
    DIR=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -f 2)
    printf "%8s %s\n" "$HRSIZE" "$DIR"
done
```

Notes:

1. bash function was found by googling (see the comments)
2. I have changed **du -ms** to **du -bs**, thus making it possible to use the conversion function that accepts bytes.
3. The 500MB limit is still hardcoded. Feel free to modify the script to accept it as argument.